Emulate a four-finger swipe gesture using Raspberry Pi
There are some existing projects which help you to turn your Raspberry Pi into a USB keyboard or mouse, see this one for example. As far as I understand, they use the HID device (/dev/hidg0) under the hood. E.g. to send the keys for "Hi":
# H (Right shift + h)
echo -ne "\x20\0\xb\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0
# i
echo -ne "\0\0\xc\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0
# Release all keys
echo -ne "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0" > /dev/hidg0

I'm trying to understand if I can use /dev/hidg0 to emulate trackpad/touchpad gestures, specifically the four-finger swipe gesture. The use-case is the following: I plug in my Raspberry Pi device into my laptop via USB, the laptop detects the Raspberry Pi device as a touchpad/trackpad/etc and Raspberry Pi emulates a four-finger swipe gesture. So could somebody please tell me if it's possible? If yes, the could you please also share some recommendations on how to implement such a thing?
